# KeyError: 'selector' while deploying streamlit python app on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, heroku, streamlit

I have deployed my python app via streamlit on heroku. The only issue I face is that when I try to display a styled dataframe with background gradient on heroku it throws me the following error:

```
KeyError: ‘selector’
Traceback:
File “/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/ScriptRunner.py”, line 319, in _run_script
exec(code, module.dict)
File “/app/test.py”, line 243, in
print(st.dataframe(etf.format_world_data(world_indices(), usd=usd)[1]))
File “/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/DeltaGenerator.py”, line 921, in dataframe
set_data_frame, “dataframe”, element_width=width, element_height=height
File “/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/DeltaGenerator.py”, line 426, in _enqueue_new_element_delta
rv = marshall_element(msg.delta.new_element)
File “/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/DeltaGenerator.py”, line 918, in set_data_frame
data_frame_proto.marshall_data_frame(data, delta.data_frame)
File “/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/elements/data_frame_proto.py”, line 54, in marshall_data_frame
_marshall_styles(proto_df.style, df, styler)
File “/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/elements/data_frame_proto.py”, line 74, in _marshall_styles
css_styles = _get_css_styles(translated_style)
File “/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/elements/data_frame_proto.py”, line 116, in _get_css_styles
cell_selector = cell_style[“selector”] # a string of the form ‘row0_col0’
```

The code works fine on my local machine and displays the styled dataframe perfectly. I have tried using st.write, st.dataframe and st.table as well, but still the error when deployed on heroku. What can I do to rectify this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrame styling has a bit of a hiccup right now, as Streamlit was relying on a private pandas method that changed in pandas 1.1:

https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1777

Try setting a hard limit on for `pandas <1.1` in your requirements.txt file, then try again with Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a problem running streamlit locally. I downgraded pandas, but that's causing other problems. Any suggestions? I may have picked the wrong day to try to learn streamlit...